# ItemDecoration Before LayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've created a custom `ItemDecoration` for a `RecyclerView` that is using a `GridLayoutManager`. The `ItemDecoration` essentially ensures that equivalent spacing between all of the child views is applied within the `RecyclerView`:

[image]

The `ItemDecoration` is working exactly as I hoped it would and I think it looks great. However, I noticed that I need to add the `ItemDecoration` before I set the layout manager for my `RecyclerView`. My main question is: Why is that?

I'm working with some legacy code that uses a `CursorLoader` to pull RSS feeds from the web and display them to the end user. For whatever reason, the layout manager is being set in `onLoadFinished()`:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(cursor);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =
            new GridLayoutManager(this, mColumnCount, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
}
```

I noticed that if I add my `ItemDecoration` within `onLoadFinished()`, the margins between the items looks bigger than it really should:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(cursor);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =
            new GridLayoutManager(this, mColumnCount, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    // Adding the custom ItemDecoration
    EqualOffsetItemDecoration itemDecoration = new EqualOffsetItemDecoration(this, R.dimen.card_view_margin, mColumnCount);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
}
```

[image]

The screenshot above shows far more margin than I was expecting since I'm only applying 8dps (the value of `card_view_margin`). However, if I add the `ItemDecoration` within `onCreate()`, then it appears as expected:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mColumnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_column_count);

    /*
    In order to have equal spacing along the edges of the screen as well as between the
    child views of the RecyclerView, an EqualOffsetItemDecoration is applied to the RecyclerView.
     */
    EqualOffsetItemDecoration itemDecoration = new EqualOffsetItemDecoration(this, R.dimen.card_view_margin, mColumnCount);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

    ...
}
```

...which is the case for the first screenshot. So why does this matter? Why do I need to add the `ItemDecoration` before applying a layout manager to my `RecyclerView`? I'm sure that this has something to do with the order in which things are executed under the hood. Any sort of explanation is greatly appreciated :)

FYI, in case anyone is interested in how I created my `ItemDecoration`, here it is:

https://github.com/mikepalarz/XYZReader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/xyzreader/ui/EqualOffsetItemDecoration.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, but I don't believe it matters if you set the layout manager before or after the item decoration. Both calls result in a request for layout.

I am going to guess that you are adding the decoration to the `RecyclerView` more than one time. Since decorations compound, you will see a greater gap with the decoration added two times (or more times) instead of just once.

Comment: That was indeed the case! I did some additional debugging and it looks like `onLoadFinished()` is called at least twice for some reason. This still doesn't completely make sense to me since I'd think a `CursorLoader` should only call this method once... But that's beyond the scope of my question and it has more to do with the legacy code that I'm working with. Appreciate your guidance on this :)